# viewpager2 with fragment where viewpager2 too after destroy first father fragment children not destroyed

Tags: android

i have activity with viewpager where in 4 fragment inside first fragment viewpager too have, if i open third> fragment inside activity, first fragment where viewpager was deleting and dastroy his children fragment doesnt destroy [this my problem in gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI1Kj.gif)

**Code creating viewpager**

```
    private fun initViewPagerFragment() {
        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter((activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager)
        adapter.addFragment(BasicInformationFragment(), "Основна інформація")
        adapter.addFragment(ContactPersonsFragment(), "Контактні особи")
        view_pager_fragment.adapter = adapter
        tabs_fragment.setupWithViewPager(view_pager_fragment)
    }
```

how to delete children or doesnt destroy first fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set **viewPager.offscreenPageLimit(4)** for keeping 4 pages in memory. Otherwise, refresh the list or request for a list item from **onVisible** of a fragment.